Finite groups of Lie type
Table $22.1$ Finite groups of Lie type from "Linear algebraic groups and finite groups of Lie type" by Malle and Testerman:
For the type $A$: $G_{sc}^{F}=\operatorname{SL}_{n}(q)$ and $G_{ad}^{F}=\operatorname{PGL}_{n}(q)$. Then it states "other isogeny types": $Z_{d/e}.\operatorname{PSL}_{n}(q).Z_{e}$ where $e|d$ and $d=\gcd(n,q-1)$ where $F$ is a Steinberg endomorphism.
I got confused by the "other isogeny types". For example, when $n=4, q=5$, there are three possibilities: $$e=2, d=4:  G_{1}:=Z_{2}.\operatorname{PSL}_{4}(5).Z_{2};\\     
e=1, d=4:  G_{2}:=Z_{4}.\operatorname{PSL}_{4}(5); \\
e=4, d=4:  G_{3}:=\operatorname{PSL}_{4}(5).Z_{4}.$$
I suppose $G_{3}=\operatorname{PGL}(4,5)$. What are $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$? How to construct these two?

It looks like $G_2={\rm SL}(4,5)$ and $G_1$ is a quotient of that.

Thanks for the input. Yes, $G_2$ does look like $SL$. But $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same order... oh. maybe $G_1$ is a covering group?

It's probably a quotient of the subgroup of index two in ${\rm GL}(4,5)$

Yes, $\mathop{\rm GL}(4,5)$ has shape $4.\mathop{\rm PSL}(4,5).4$ (uniserial) so you just knock a two off top and bottom.
